# How to make Data Loader for "Multi-Head" Regression which can be used with HuggingFace Transformers & Trainer?

Tags: pytorch, nlp, regression, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I am working on a Multi head regression problem where for each text I want to predict 5 scores. You can do this by setting `problem_type = 'regression'` [as given in transformers code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/7ae6f070044b0171a71f3269613bf02fd9fca6f2/src/transformers/models/deberta_v2/modeling_deberta_v2.py#L1327C1-L1333C1)

Issue is that when I run my model with `Trainer`, it gives an error like:

## Error:

```
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate truncation and/or padding with 'padding=True' 'truncation=True' to have batched tensors with the same length. Perhaps your features (`labels` in this case) have excessive nesting (inputs type `list` where type `int` is expected).
```

It worked with `num_classes = 1` but when I do it with 5, it throws this error. Below are the minimal code for my model, data.

## Model

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", 
                                                           num_labels=5, 
                                                          problem_type = "regression")
```

## Custom DataLoader:

```
class MultiRegressionDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, texts, labels):
        self.labels = labels
        self.texts = texts
        

    def __getitem__(self, idx, sanity_check = False):
        output = tokenizer(self.texts[idx], truncation=True,
                              padding="max_length",
                              max_length = 128) # This returns a dict

        output['labels'] = torch.tensor(self.labels[idx])
        
        return output

data = MultiRegressionDataset(["text1", "text2"], [[1,2,3,4,5], [5,4,3,2,1]])

data.__getitem__(0) # Gives a value
```

Tried doing it with

1. `output['labels'] = torch.tensor(self.labels[idx]).unsqueeze(-1)`
2. Combination of  `return_tensors = "pt"` with the above

Nothing worked. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue might be related to the format of the labels and how they are being handled during tokenization. The error suggests that there might be an inconsistency in the length of the tensors for different samples in a batch.

Here's a revised version of your `MultiRegressionDataset` class that might help resolve the issue:

```
class MultiRegressionDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, texts, labels):
        self.labels = labels
        self.texts = texts
        self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.texts)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        encoding = self.tokenizer(self.texts[idx], truncation=True, padding="max_length", max_length=128, return_tensors="pt")
        
        # Ensure labels are converted to float
        labels = torch.tensor(self.labels[idx], dtype=torch.float32)
        
        # Flatten the labels if needed
        # labels = labels.view(-1)
        
        # Remove nested structure in the labels
        labels = labels.squeeze() if labels.dim() > 1 else labels

        # Update the encoding dictionary with the labels
        encoding['labels'] = labels

        return encoding
```

Make sure to replace the tokenization logic and model loading with your actual tokenizer and model. After making these changes, try training your model again and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Thanks for the update. With return_tensors=“pt”, wouldn’t it create an issue as each of it would be a batch in itself while creating a batch of size, let’s say 32? I’m using Trainer and TrainingArguments.